# Oracle PL/SQL: Compilation problems with triggers - ORA-00904 errors and invalid identifiers

Tags: sql, database, triggers, oracle-sqldeveloper, ora-00904

I'm making different constraints on my database for a project, but I have errors that I can't get out of and I just don't understand the meaning.

I work on SQL Developer with Oracle.

[image]

Here is my script to create my DB:

```
sql

-- Table Video
CREATE TABLE Video (
  ID INTEGER,
  title VARCHAR(200),
  description VARCHAR(500),
  main_theme VARCHAR(100),
  type VARCHAR2(50),
  link VARCHAR(500),
  duration VARCHAR(26),
  customer_rating DECIMAL(3,2),
  classification VARCHAR(50),
  country VARCHAR(50),
  year_production INTEGER,
  CONSTRAINT PK_Video PRIMARY KEY (ID)
);

-- Table Entertainment
CREATE TABLE Entertainment (
  ID INTEGER,
  video_ID INT,
  CONSTRAINT PK_Entertainment PRIMARY KEY (ID),
  CONSTRAINT FK_Entertainment_Video FOREIGN KEY (video_ID) REFERENCES Video(ID)
);

-- Table Children
CREATE TABLE Children (
  ID INTEGER,
  video_ID INT,
  CONSTRAINT PK_Children PRIMARY KEY (ID),
  CONSTRAINT FK_Children_Video FOREIGN KEY (video_ID) REFERENCES Video(ID)
);

-- Table Cinema
CREATE TABLE Cinema (
  ID INTEGER,
  video_ID INT,
  CONSTRAINT PK_Cinema PRIMARY KEY (ID),
  CONSTRAINT FK_Cinema_Video FOREIGN KEY (video_ID) REFERENCES Video(ID)
);

-- Table Episode
CREATE TABLE Episode (
  ID INTEGER,
  video_ID INT,
  name_episode VARCHAR(100),
  CONSTRAINT PK_Episode PRIMARY KEY (ID),
  CONSTRAINT FK_Episode_Video FOREIGN KEY (video_ID) REFERENCES Video(ID)
);

-- Table Format
CREATE TABLE Format (
  video_ID INTEGER,
  name VARCHAR(100),
  extension VARCHAR(50),
  CONSTRAINT PK_Format PRIMARY KEY (video_ID),
  CONSTRAINT FK_Format_Video FOREIGN KEY (video_ID) REFERENCES Video(ID)
);

-- Table Version
CREATE TABLE Version (
  ID INTEGER,
  video_ID INTEGER,
  price DECIMAL(4,2),
  quality VARCHAR(10),
  CONSTRAINT PK_Version PRIMARY KEY (ID),
  CONSTRAINT FK_Version_Video FOREIGN KEY (video_ID) REFERENCES Video(ID)
);

-- Table Software
CREATE TABLE Software (
  nom_software VARCHAR(100),
  CONSTRAINT PK_Software PRIMARY KEY (nom_software)
);

-- Table Extension
CREATE TABLE Extension (
  name VARCHAR(50),
  CONSTRAINT PK_Extension PRIMARY KEY (name) 
);

-- Table Keyword
CREATE TABLE Keyword (
  keyword VARCHAR(50),
  CONSTRAINT PK_Keyword PRIMARY KEY (keyword)
);

-- Table Type_Mime
CREATE TABLE Type_Mime (
  name VARCHAR(50),
  CONSTRAINT PK_Type_Mime PRIMARY KEY (name)
);

-- Table Customer
CREATE TABLE Customer (
  ID INTEGER,
  first_name VARCHAR(50),
  last_name VARCHAR(50),
  postal_address VARCHAR(100),
  email VARCHAR(100),
  phone_number VARCHAR(20),
  password VARCHAR(100),
  CONSTRAINT PK_Customer PRIMARY KEY (ID)
);

-- Table Type_Subscription
CREATE TABLE Type_Subscription (
  name VARCHAR(100),
  nb_cinema INTEGER,
  nb_serie INTEGER,
  nb_children INTEGER,
  nb_entertainment INTEGER,
  price DECIMAL(4,2),
  CONSTRAINT PK_Type_Subscription PRIMARY KEY (name)
);

-- Table Season
CREATE TABLE Season (
  ID INTEGER,
  description VARCHAR(500),
  CONSTRAINT PK_Season PRIMARY KEY (ID)
);

-- Table Serie
CREATE TABLE Serie (
  ID INTEGER,
  description VARCHAR(500),
  CONSTRAINT PK_Serie PRIMARY KEY (ID)
);

-- Table Worker
CREATE TABLE Worker (
  ID INTEGER,
  first_name VARCHAR(50),
  last_name VARCHAR(50),
  CONSTRAINT PK_Worker PRIMARY KEY (ID)
);

-- Table Video_Keyword
CREATE TABLE Video_Keyword (
  video_ID INTEGER,
  keyword VARCHAR(50),
  CONSTRAINT PK_Video_Keyword PRIMARY KEY (video_ID, keyword),
  CONSTRAINT FK_Video_Keyword_Video FOREIGN KEY (video_ID) REFERENCES Video(ID),
  CONSTRAINT FK_Video_Keyword_Keyword FOREIGN KEY (keyword) REFERENCES Keyword(keyword)
);

-- Table Cinema_Actor
CREATE TABLE Cinema_Actor (
  cinema_ID INTEGER,
  worker_ID INTEGER,
  CONSTRAINT PK_Cinema_Actor PRIMARY KEY (cinema_ID, worker_ID),
  CONSTRAINT FK_Cinema_Actor_Cinema FOREIGN KEY (cinema_ID) REFERENCES Cinema(ID),
  CONSTRAINT FK_Cinema_Actor_Worker FOREIGN KEY (worker_ID) REFERENCES Worker(ID)
);

-- Table Cinema_Scriptwriter
CREATE TABLE Cinema_Scriptwriter (
  cinema_ID INTEGER,
  worker_ID INTEGER,
  CONSTRAINT PK_Cinema_Scriptwriter PRIMARY KEY (cinema_ID, worker_ID),
  CONSTRAINT FK_Cinema_Scriptwriter_Cinema FOREIGN KEY (cinema_ID) REFERENCES Cinema(ID),
  CONSTRAINT FK_Cinema_Scriptwriter_Worker FOREIGN KEY (worker_ID) REFERENCES Worker(ID)
);

-- Table Children_Compositor
CREATE TABLE Children_Compositor (
  children_ID INTEGER,
  worker_ID INTEGER,
  CONSTRAINT PK_Children_Compositor PRIMARY KEY (children_ID, worker_ID),
  CONSTRAINT FK_Children_Compositor_Children FOREIGN KEY (children_ID) REFERENCES Children(ID),
  CONSTRAINT FK_Children_Compositor_Worker FOREIGN KEY (worker_ID) REFERENCES Worker(ID)
);

-- Table Children_Scriptwriter
CREATE TABLE Children_Scriptwriter (
  children_ID INTEGER,
  worker_ID INTEGER,
  CONSTRAINT PK_Children_Scriptwriter PRIMARY KEY (children_ID, worker_ID),
  CONSTRAINT FK_Children_Scriptwriter_Children FOREIGN KEY (children_ID) REFERENCES Children(ID),
  CONSTRAINT FK_Children_Scriptwriter_Worker FOREIGN KEY (worker_ID) REFERENCES Worker(ID)
);

-- Table Entertainment_Scriptwriter
CREATE TABLE Entertainment_Scriptwriter (
  entertainment_ID INTEGER,
  worker_ID INTEGER,
  CONSTRAINT PK_Entertainment_Scriptwriter PRIMARY KEY (entertainment_ID, worker_ID),
  CONSTRAINT FK_Entertainment_Scriptwriter_Entertainment FOREIGN KEY (entertainment_ID) REFERENCES Entertainment(ID),
  CONSTRAINT FK_Entertainment_Scriptwriter_Worker FOREIGN KEY (worker_ID) REFERENCES Worker(ID)
);

-- Table Entertainment_Stage_director
CREATE TABLE Entertainment_Stage_director (
  entertainment_ID INTEGER,
  worker_ID INTEGER,
  CONSTRAINT PK_Entertainment_Stage_director PRIMARY KEY (entertainment_ID, worker_ID),
  CONSTRAINT FK_Entertainment_Stage_director_Entertainment FOREIGN KEY (entertainment_ID) REFERENCES Entertainment(ID),
  CONSTRAINT FK_Entertainment_Stage_director_Worker FOREIGN KEY (worker_ID) REFERENCES Worker(ID)
);

-- Table Entertainment_Interpreter
CREATE TABLE Entertainment_Interpreter (
  entertainment_ID INTEGER,
  worker_ID INTEGER,
  CONSTRAINT PK_Entertainment_Interpreter PRIMARY KEY (entertainment_ID, worker_ID),
  CONSTRAINT FK_Entertainment_Interpreter_Entertainment FOREIGN KEY (entertainment_ID) REFERENCES Entertainment(ID),
  CONSTRAINT FK_Entertainment_Interpreter_Worker FOREIGN KEY (worker_ID) REFERENCES Worker(ID)
);

-- Table Season_Actor
CREATE TABLE Season_Actor (
  season_ID INTEGER,
  worker_ID INTEGER,
  CONSTRAINT PK_Season_Actor PRIMARY KEY (season_ID, worker_ID),
  CONSTRAINT FK_Season_Actor_Season FOREIGN KEY (season_ID) REFERENCES Season(ID),
  CONSTRAINT FK_Season_Actor_Worker FOREIGN KEY (worker_ID) REFERENCES Worker(ID)
);

-- Table Season_Producer
CREATE TABLE Season_Producer (
  season_ID INTEGER,
  worker_ID INTEGER,
  CONSTRAINT PK_Season_Producer PRIMARY KEY (season_ID, worker_ID),
  CONSTRAINT FK_Season_Producer_Season FOREIGN KEY (season_ID) REFERENCES Season(ID),
  CONSTRAINT FK_Season_Producer_Worker FOREIGN KEY (worker_ID) REFERENCES Worker(ID)
);

-- Table Buy
CREATE TABLE Buy (
  customer_ID INTEGER,
  version_ID INTEGER,
  rating DECIMAL(3, 2),
  CONSTRAINT PK_Buy PRIMARY KEY (customer_ID, version_ID),
  CONSTRAINT FK_Buy_Customer FOREIGN KEY (customer_ID) REFERENCES Customer(ID),
  CONSTRAINT FK_Buy_Version FOREIGN KEY (version_ID) REFERENCES Version(ID)
);

-- Table Rent
CREATE TABLE Rent (
  customer_ID INTEGER,
  version_ID INTEGER,
  start_date DATE,
  end_date DATE,
  rating DECIMAL(3, 2),
  CONSTRAINT PK_Rent PRIMARY KEY (customer_ID, version_ID),
  CONSTRAINT FK_Rent_Customer FOREIGN KEY (customer_ID) REFERENCES Customer(ID),
  CONSTRAINT FK_Rent_Version FOREIGN KEY (version_ID) REFERENCES Version(ID)
);
```

Here is also my entire script for different constraints that I have explained in comments to each one:

```
sql

-- Constraint 1: a link to a trailer must start with http
ALTER TABLE Video
ADD CONSTRAINT CK_Video_Link_HTTP CHECK (link LIKE 'http%');

-- Constraint 2: the evaluation on a content must be between 0 and 5
ALTER TABLE Video
ADD CONSTRAINT CK_Video_Rating_Between CHECK (customer_rating BETWEEN 0 AND 5);

-- Constraint 3: the year of production must be higher than 1900
ALTER TABLE Video
ADD CONSTRAINT CK_Video_Year_GT_1900 CHECK (year_production > 1900);

-- Constraint 4: passwords must be at least 8 characters long, contain letters and numbers, and include at least one capital letter and one special character
ALTER TABLE Customer
ADD CONSTRAINT CK_Customer_Password_Regex CHECK (REGEXP_LIKE(password, '(?=.*\d)(?=.*[a-z])(?=.*[A-Z])(?=.*[!@#$%^&*()])(.{8,})'));

-- Constraint 5: Youth content cannot be under 16 or under 18
CREATE OR REPLACE TRIGGER trg_children_classification
BEFORE INSERT OR UPDATE OF classification ON Video
FOR EACH ROW
WHEN (NEW.type = 'Children')
DECLARE
BEGIN
  IF :NEW.classification IN ('-16', '-18') THEN
    RAISE_APPLICATION_ERROR(-20003, 'Youth content cannot be under 16 or under 18');
  END IF;
END;
/

-- Constraint 6: the number of subscriber rentals must be less than or equal to that authorized by their subscriptions
CREATE OR REPLACE TRIGGER trg_rent_limit
BEFORE INSERT ON Rent
FOR EACH ROW
DECLARE
  v_rent_count NUMBER;
  v_max_rent_count NUMBER;
BEGIN
  SELECT COUNT(*)
  INTO v_rent_count
  FROM Rent
  WHERE customer_ID = :NEW.customer_ID;

  SELECT ts.nb_cinema + ts.nb_serie + ts.nb_children + ts.nb_entertainment
  INTO v_max_rent_count
  FROM Customer c
  JOIN Type_Subscription ts ON c.type_subscription = ts.ID
  WHERE c.ID = :NEW.customer_ID;

  IF v_rent_count >= v_max_rent_count THEN
    RAISE_APPLICATION_ERROR(-20002, 'Subscribers rentals must be less than or equal to the number authorized by their subscriptions');
  END IF;
END;
/

-- Constraint 7: a customer cannot have two subscriptions at the same time
CREATE OR REPLACE TRIGGER trg_customer_subscription
BEFORE INSERT ON Rent
FOR EACH ROW
DECLARE
  v_rent_duration NUMBER;
BEGIN
  SELECT ts.nb_days
  INTO v_rent_duration
  FROM Customer c
  JOIN Type_Subscription ts ON c.type_subscription_id = ts.ID
  WHERE c.ID = :NEW.customer_ID;

  :NEW.end_date := :NEW.start_date + v_rent_duration;
END;
/

-- Constraint 8: A subscriber cannot rent content if the rental date for that content has passed
CREATE OR REPLACE TRIGGER trg_rent_date
BEFORE INSERT ON Rent
FOR EACH ROW
DECLARE
  v_content_date DATE;
BEGIN
  SELECT r.end_date
  INTO v_content_date
  FROM Video v
  JOIN Rent r ON v.ID = r.video_ID
  WHERE r.ID = :NEW.version_ID;

  IF v_content_date > SYSDATE THEN
    RAISE_APPLICATION_ERROR(-20004, 'A subscriber cannot rent content if the rental date for that content has passed');
  END IF;
END;
/
```

```
And here are the errors that are displayed to me in Console.

Trigger element TRG_CHILDREN_CLASSIFICATION compiled


Trigger element TRG_RENT_LIMIT compiled

LINE/COL ERROR
--------- -------------------------------------------------------------
10/3 PL/SQL: SQL Statement ignored
13/54 PL/SQL: ORA-00904: "TS". "ID": invalid identifier
Errors: consult the compiler log

Trigger element TRG_CUSTOMER_SUBSCRIPTION compiled

LINE/COL ERROR
--------- -------------------------------------------------------------
4/3 PL/SQL: SQL Statement ignored
7/57 PL/SQL: ORA-00904: "TS". "ID": invalid identifier
Errors: consult the compiler log

Trigger element TRG_RENT_DATE compiled

LINE/COL ERROR
--------- -------------------------------------------------------------
4/3 PL/SQL: SQL Statement ignored
7/25 PL/SQL: ORA-00904: "R". "VIDEO_ID": invalid identifier
Errors: consult the compiler log
```

The newspaper displays 2 errors to me:
"Error(105,3): PL/SQL: SQL Statement ignored" and
"Error(108,25): PL/SQL: ORA-00904: "R". "VIDEO_ID": invalid identifier"

The first one points me to the line:

"IF :NEW.classification IN ('-16', '-18') THEN" from the children_classification trigger.

The second error simply points me to the END at the end of the Trigger.

I tried For the trg_rent_limit trigger to modify the problematic line as follows:

```
JOIN Type_Subscription ts ON c.type_subscription = ts.name
```

but replacing the name with the ts.ID.

I also tried to modify a lot of things on the trigger_rent_date (because I thought that the problem came from there with incorrect references) but still the same problem.

And I also have the impression that the problem is not with the children_classification but with the rent_date.

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Divide-and-conquer_algorithm

Comment: Your `type_subscription` table does not have a column of "ID" yet you try to join on it here: `JOIN Type_Subscription ts ON c.type_subscription = ts.ID`. Also, `customer` table does not have a column named "type_subscription", so that join doesn't work on either end.

Comment: @Isolated

Indeed, but when I change it I get this

13/32 PL/SQL: ORA-00904: "C". "TYPE_SUBSCRIPTION": invalid identifier

Comment: RAISE_APPLICATION_ERROR(-20002, 'Subscribers' rentals.....     You closed the string inproperly

Comment: I don't see how you could directly join CUSTOMER with TYPE_SUBSCRIPTION. Perhaps the Customer table is missing a column?

Comment: @Isolated I added a schema to my database

Comment: @Sergey small error of collage on the site simply, it is corrected!

Comment: To cut a long story short, you have to revise tables involved in triggers that failed compilation and make sure that columns you use actually exist. Because, they don't (not all of them). Take your time, you know what's related to what and how. Once you fix that, triggers will compile.

Comment: @Littlefoot that's the problem... I spent about 5 hours correcting error after error but now I'm totally blocked and I don't see why it's still blocked...

Comment: @Elblocktri Like I mentioned, you are trying to join on columns that don't exist. Fix the joins first, test the sql to make sure they work, then run.

Answer (score 0):

It is too much text to illustrate in a limited comment, so - here you are.

All tables and constraints up to this one are successfully created, but this one fails:

```
SQL> -- Constraint 6: the number of subscriber rentals must be less than or equal to that authorized by their subscriptions
SQL> CREATE OR REPLACE TRIGGER trg_rent_limit
  2  BEFORE INSERT ON Rent
  3  FOR EACH ROW
  4  DECLARE
  5    v_rent_count NUMBER;
  6    v_max_rent_count NUMBER;
  7  BEGIN
  8    SELECT COUNT(*)
  9    INTO v_rent_count
 10    FROM Rent
 11    WHERE customer_ID = :NEW.customer_ID;
 12
 13    SELECT ts.nb_cinema + ts.nb_serie + ts.nb_children + ts.nb_entertainment
 14    INTO v_max_rent_count
 15    FROM Customer c
 16    JOIN Type_Subscription ts ON c.type_subscription = ts.ID
 17    WHERE c.ID = :NEW.customer_ID;
 18
 19    IF v_rent_count >= v_max_rent_count THEN
 20      RAISE_APPLICATION_ERROR(-20002, 'Subscribers rentals must be less than or equal to the number authorized by their subscriptions');
 21    END IF;
 22  END;
 23  /

Warning: Trigger created with compilation errors.

SQL> show err
Errors for TRIGGER TRG_RENT_LIMIT:

LINE/COL ERROR
-------- -----------------------------------------------------------------
10/3     PL/SQL: SQL Statement ignored
13/54    PL/SQL: ORA-00904: "TS"."ID": invalid identifier
SQL>
```

Query that failed is:

```
SQL> SELECT ts.nb_cinema + ts.nb_serie + ts.nb_children + ts.nb_entertainment
  2    FROM Customer c
  3    JOIN Type_Subscription ts ON c.type_subscription = ts.ID;
  JOIN Type_Subscription ts ON c.type_subscription = ts.ID
                                                     *
ERROR at line 3:
ORA-00904: "TS"."ID": invalid identifier


SQL>
```

It says that `customer` table should contain column named `type_subscription`; does it?

```
SQL> desc customer
 Name                                      Null?    Type
 ----------------------------------------- -------- ----------------------------
 ID                                        NOT NULL NUMBER(38)
 FIRST_NAME                                         VARCHAR2(50)
 LAST_NAME                                          VARCHAR2(50)
 POSTAL_ADDRESS                                     VARCHAR2(100)
 EMAIL                                              VARCHAR2(100)
 PHONE_NUMBER                                       VARCHAR2(20)
 PASSWORD                                           VARCHAR2(100)
```

Nope, no `type_subscription` column here.

Error also says that `type_subscription` table should contain `id` column:

```
SQL> desc type_subscription
 Name                                      Null?    Type
 ----------------------------------------- -------- ----------------------------
 NAME                                      NOT NULL VARCHAR2(100)
 NB_CINEMA                                          NUMBER(38)
 NB_SERIE                                           NUMBER(38)
 NB_CHILDREN                                        NUMBER(38)
 NB_ENTERTAINMENT                                   NUMBER(38)
 PRICE                                              NUMBER(4,2)

SQL>
```

Nope, no `id` column here either.

Therefore, how can you expect that query/trigger to work?

---

As I said: revise tables involved and **fix what's missing**.